# Cascade notation not working for .where method in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run the following example,

```
void main() {
  List data = ['asdf', null, 'b'];
  List bata = data
    ..add('cc')
    ..where((item) => item != null);
  print(bata);
}
```

I get the following output,

```
[asdf, null, b, cc]
```

Why isn't `.where` method filtering `null` from the List?

Comment: The entire point of doing `x..y()` is to invoke `y`, discard its return value, and evaluate the entire expression to `x`.  `Iterable.where` returns a *new* `Iterable`; it does not mutate the original one.  You want `var bata = (data..add(...)).where(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `.where()` method isn't filtering null values from the list is that you're using the cascade notation (`..`) which returns the original object upon which the methods are being called. In your case, the original `data` list is being modified with the `add` method and then returned, ignoring the result of the `where` method.

If you want to create a new list with the null values filtered out, you can use the method chaining (using `.`) instead of the cascade notation. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
void main() {
  List data = ['asdf', null, 'b'];
  List bata = data
    .toList() // Create a new list to avoid modifying the original data list
    ..add('cc');
  List filteredBata = bata.where((item) => item != null).toList();
  print(filteredBata);
}
```

This will output:

```
[asdf, b, cc]
```

In this code, I first create a new list with `toList()` before adding the new element to it, so that the original `data` list remains unchanged. Then, I use the `where` method to filter out the null values and convert the result back to a list with `toList()`.